# melting effect of card in memory game

Tags: javascript

I have the following code snippest in memory game

```
if (mycards.length < 2)
    {
    mycards.push(elem.style.backgroundColor);
    myelemcards.push(elem);
    console.log(myelemcards);
    elem.classList.remove('reverse');

        if (mycards.length == 2)
        {
            if (mycards[0] == mycards[1])
            {
                score++;
                document.querySelector("result").innerHTML = score;
                setTimeout(function ()
                {
                myelemcards[0].classList.add('card');
                myelemcards[1].classList.add('card');
                }, 1000)
    myelemcards[1].remove()
    myelemcards[0].remove();

}
```

I need to do  a melting effect when 2 cards are the same and I have to make the cards not move from their place (if 2 cards are the same only they disappear and the cards order doesn't change )
tried something like this

```
function go(elem)
{
   
    if (mycards.length < 2)
    {
    mycards.push(elem.style.backgroundColor);
    myelemcards.push(elem);
    console.log(myelemcards);
    elem.classList.remove('reverse');

        if (mycards.length == 2)
        {
            if (mycards[0] == mycards[1])
            {
                score++;
                document.querySelector("result").innerHTML = score;
                setTimeout(function ()
                {
                myelemcards[0].classList.add('card');
                myelemcards[1].classList.add('card');
                }, 1000)
    delete myelemcards[1];
    delete myelemcards[0];

}
```

melting I have no idea , the delete seems to work

Comment: Deleting items only sets the values to null and does not remove them from the array. Use splice to mutate the original array, or recreate with slice method

Comment: how would you remove them as needed so they wouldn't change their location

Comment: Perhaps update your question with a smaller example with complete code. I can't understand your intention above. You have 2 arrays you are changing above and the concept of melting is confusing the real intention of repositioning items in a single array.